# Uploading files on to server using spring mvc

Tags: spring-mvc, jsp, tomcat9

I am trying to upload list of files to the server using spring MVC. But i am able to store on to the c drive,but i don't know how to upload onto server.Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

create a folder inside the Tomcat 9 (server) directory as follows

> .../Apache Software Foundation/Tomcat 9/FileUpload

then, you can access the above directory (FileUpload) in java

```
File fileUpload = new File(System.getProperty("catalina.base"), "FileUpload");
```

but, if you  use the eclipse ide, in the development time you cannot access the above directory and you should be created a folder as same name (FileUpload) in the following directory for eclipse

> .../workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/FileUpload

you can use above directory for development and testing purpose

Comment: uploading file onto server is fine ,but how to store it permanently after even closing application.

Comment: ur question is not clear. what is the closing app. is it web application or ide?

Comment: Web application not IDE