# Can not write images to src/main/resources/static when uploaded on deployment server

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

The problem: For some reason when I'm deploying my spring application I can not write to `src/main/resources/static/` as it's not found by the server.

This is how I'm handling the IO

### Write to src/main/resources/static

```java
String filename="src/main/resources/static/images/profileImages/"+im.getAedName();
//im.getAedName() = "user.png"
    
        
Path pathToFile = Paths.get(filename);
       
byte[] data = DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(im.getImage());
        
        
try {
        Files.write(pathToFile,data);
} catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
}
```

### Read from html using thymeleaf

```html
th:src="@{'/images/profileImages/'+${loggedinUser.photo}}"
```

where `${loggedinUser.photo}` is `user.png`

### Works just fine on localhost

[image]

> When I upload the application to the web, it seems that it can not
> write to `src/main/resources/static/images/profileImages` as it can
> not find the directory.

### What i've tried

- add resource location on MVC (probably did something wrong here)

```java
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(final ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/images/profileImages/**").addResourceLocations("file:/images/profileImages");
    }
```

- print absolute path on the deployment server and write it there (didn't work)

What else can i try?

Thank you!

Edit1: Logs on deployment server:

> 2020-10-04T13:12:53.102708007Z: [ERROR]  java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: src/main/resources/static/images/profileImages/nicksterg9.png
> 2020-10-04T13:12:53.102738308Z: [ERROR]     at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(Unknown Source)
> 2020-10-04T13:12:53.102752309Z: [ERROR]     at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(Unknown Source)
> 2020-10-04T13:12:53.102756009Z: [ERROR]     at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(Unknown Source)
> 2020-10-04T13:12:53.102768409Z: [ERROR]     at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.newByteChannel(Unknown Source)
> 2020-10-04T13:12:53.102772009Z: [ERROR]     at java.base/java.nio.file.spi.FileSystemProvider.newOutputStream(Unknown Source)
> 2020-10-04T13:12:53.102775309Z: [ERROR]     at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.newOutputStream(Unknown Source)
> 2020-10-04T13:12:53.102778410Z: [ERROR]     at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.write(Unknown Source)

Comment: Create the directory on the server?

Comment: Keep in mind, `https://url/images/profileImages/user.png` exists and it gets returned as well

Comment: you are right, i love you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Uploading files on to server using spring mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60335303/uploading-files-on-to-server-using-spring-mvc)

Comment: @Lakshan not quite, the thing is, I can write to the directory, there is a difficulty when I try to read from it, is there any way to initialize a path to spring so it knows that dir?

Comment: @PhillAlexakis please refer this article, https://www.callicoder.com/spring-boot-file-upload-download-rest-api-example/. it will be helpful you.